# Athena is not loading Database and Table list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

It's as simple as that. Athena used to load databases and tables that I crawled using Glue. The data is present in S3 and Athena used to work before. But all of a sudden the loading icon goes round and round but it doesn't load the list of databases and tables.

I'm in the right region. It works when I send the queries through Python/SageMaker i.e. I use awswrangler and the data output from that is fine. But it's not possible to query within Athena itself even though I used to do it before.

Totally stumped on what the problem could be as I have no clues.

Answer (score 3):

This has been solved. I am not sure what the fix was (This has been an issue since atleast 3 months and I have tried solving it before with similar methods).

But I did two things before it 'fixed itself':

1. Tried changing the Athena output location through the workgroup settings.
2. Tried changing the same(I'm not sure if both settings point to the same property) through the settings icon on the right top of the page.

And suddenly the list of databases and tables shows up in the Query Editor page.

Answer (score 1):

It got solved when I created a new output table for AWS Glue, in my case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35805297)